# Date Formatter failing on a correct date

Tags: swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have a function that parses a String to Date. The function is working correctly on all dates except "26-3-2017".
If I manipulate the date and make it "26-3-2016" everything works correctly.
Even more, I tried the function on an array of dates it works fine on all of them except the "26-3-2017".

**CODE**

```
import Foundation
let dates = ["1-11-2017",
"17-10-2017",
"16-10-2017",
"13-10-2017",
"13-10-2017",
"10-10-2017",
"5-10-2017",
"4-10-2017",
"2-10-2017",
"26-9-2017",
"20-9-2017",
"18-9-2017",
"18-9-2017",
"27-5-2017",
"15-5-2017",
"9-5-2017",
"9-5-2017",
"5-5-2017",
"12-4-2017",
"26-3-2017",
"25-3-2017",
"22-3-2017",
"15-3-2017",
"10-3-2017",
"10-3-2017",
"17-2-2017",
"18-12-2016",
"17-12-2016",
"5-12-2016",
"6-12-2016",
"5-12-2016",
"6-12-2016",
"5-12-2016",
"6-12-2016",
"2-12-2016",
"30-11-2016",
"30-11-2016",
"30-11-2016",
"25-11-2016",
"25-11-2016",
"29-11-2016",
"23-11-2016",
"18-11-2016",
"18-11-2016",
"21-10-2016",
"21-10-2016",
"17-10-2016",
"17-10-2016",
"14-10-2016",
"12-10-2016",
"12-10-2016",
"17-12-2016",
"7-10-2016",
"23-7-2016",
"22-7-2016",
"22-7-2016",
"22-7-2016",
"21-7-2016"]

func getDate(dateString:String, withFormat format:String = "d-M-yyyy") -> Date?{
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat  = format

    return dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)!
}

for date in dates{

    print (getDate(dateString: date))
}
```

Comment: On 26-3-2017 at midnight, the clocks were [adjusted one hour forward for the daylight saving time](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/lebanon/beirut) in Beirut, therefore date "26-3-2017 00:00" does not exist. The linked-to Q&A contains possible solutions.

Comment: I don't know how this is even possible! They should've handled it from their end. Thank you for this answer it was exactly my issue